# closure return function doesn't changes scoped variable

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function testLet(){
    var x=9;
    return{
        y:x,
        getX: function(){
            return ++x;
        },
    }
}

var obj = new testLet();
console.log(obj.y); //9 as expected
console.log(obj.getX()); //10 as expected
console.log(obj.getX()); //11 as expected
console.log(obj.y); //I expect it 11.. but it stays 9
```

Why the last line returns 9 instead of 11 as x is in the same scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y:x` means "Copy the current value of `x` to the property `y`".

The value, at the time, is `9`.

Subsequent changes to the value of `x` won't change the value of `y`.

---

You can either change your `getX` function to modify `this.y`, or you can change the `y` property to be a getter function which reads the current value of `x`.

Comment: Thanks.. When I tried second option of y as a function returning x, I see both the function share the same x. If y as a function makes any change to x valriable, getterX also has the updated value. So, is it safe to assume that   Differnt functions in return method share variable but when assignment is as a variable, it is a separate copy?